# How to implement setText to integer dataType in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, integer, settext

[I want to set data from my editText which has integer typedata. if it is string, we can make setTake, but how we can implement it at integer?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kCyl.png)

The warning is

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
setText(CharSequence!) defined in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
setText(Int) defined in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

Comment: you can type cast the integer to the String

Comment: it doesn't work. because the warning is None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
setText(CharSequence!) defined in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
setText(Int) defined in com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows `data` is of type `UserDto`. I don't know what that class looks like but it has a field called `phoneNumber`. This is what you are passing to `setText()`. I can't tell what type this `phoneNumber` is because you haven't shown us your `UserDto` class but the error tells us that it's neither an `Int` nor `CharSequence`, which it needs to be. You can try to do this maybe to make it work

```
binding.etPhone.setText(data.phoneNumber.toString())
```